# jQueryUI Sortable not displaying inline

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Im having a problem displaying the my list imtesm when using the jQueryUI "sortable".

I havent uploaded any code because its the same as the jQueryUI example [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default)

This is the Example on the jQueryUI Site:
[image: jQueryUI Example]

This is what mine looks like:
[image: My Output]

I tried setting the `display` style attribute to `inline` in the `<li>` tag and this was the result:
[image: Display = Inline Example]

Im not very good at css, but i think its playing a role in this issue.

How do I get the elements to stay inline?

Please help,
Thanks in Advance,
Grant

Comment: Grant, have you put any custom css yet?

Answer (score -1):

Try different browsers. Full code should be:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Working for me.

Comment: Won't work @ Grants Machine because of the absolute Links and the therefore missing css. If you copy and paste the JQuery-Website, do it properly. This probably won't help him.

Comment: Did work for me even with the the missing css. The font size is the only thing that changes when using the css file with an absolute path.